# text not wrapping in table cell using iText5 for .NET

Tags: c#, pdf, printing, itext

I have a function that generates a text report. I get a list of document text from the database and I create a PDF report. The PDF report format should be as follows

```
logo(top left).........some static text about company (top right)

[header information that is......................................
.........................different for each document in the list]  

[.....................document text.............................]

date(bottom left)              page count(bottom right)
```

The document text may run more than one page and in that case the header information for that document repeats. And, if the document text runs a second page and terminates in mid page we start the next document on a new page. Here is my attempt:

```
public static void printDocument(List<PdfData> lst, ref MemoryStream memoryStream)
{
        iTextSharp.text.Font baseFontBig = new     iTextSharp.text.Font(iTextSharp.text.Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 12f, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD, iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.BLACK);

        iTextSharp.text.Document document = new iTextSharp.text.Document(PageSize.LETTER, 40, 25, 30, 30);
        PDFEvents e = new PDFEvents();
        PdfWriter pw = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, memoryStream);
        pw.PageEvent = e;
        document.Open();

        for (int i = 0; i < lst.Count; i++)
        {
            PdfPTable mainTable = new PdfPTable(2);
            PdfPTable outerTable = new PdfPTable(4);
            PdfPTable contentTable = new PdfPTable(1);

            mainTable.KeepTogether = true;

            outerTable.WidthPercentage = 50;
            outerTable.KeepTogether = false;
            outerTable.TotalWidth = 550f;
            float[] sglTblHdWidths = new float[4];
            sglTblHdWidths[0] = 5f;
            sglTblHdWidths[1] = 15f;
            sglTblHdWidths[2] = 5f;
            sglTblHdWidths[3] = 5f;
            outerTable.SetWidths(sglTblHdWidths);
            outerTable.LockedWidth = true;
            contentTable.LockedWidth = true;
            outerTable.KeepTogether = true;

            contentTable.WidthPercentage = 90;
            contentTable.KeepTogether = false;
            contentTable.TotalWidth = 800f;
            contentTable.SpacingBefore = 30f;

            string documentIdentifier = lst[i].patient;
            string documentStatus =lst[i].documentStatus;



            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            sb.Append(lst[i].documentText);



            iTextSharp.text.Paragraph documentStatusP = new iTextSharp.text.Paragraph(documentStatus, new iTextSharp.text.Font(iTextSharp.text.Font.FontFamily.COURIER, 12, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD, iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.BLACK));
            iTextSharp.text.Paragraph patient = new iTextSharp.text.Paragraph(documentIdentifier, new iTextSharp.text.Font(iTextSharp.text.Font.FontFamily.COURIER, 12, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD, iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.BLACK));
            iTextSharp.text.Paragraph content = new iTextSharp.text.Paragraph(sb.ToString(), new iTextSharp.text.Font(iTextSharp.text.Font.FontFamily.COURIER, 10));
            iTextSharp.text.Paragraph empty = new iTextSharp.text.Paragraph("", new iTextSharp.text.Font(iTextSharp.text.Font.FontFamily.COURIER, 12));



            #region Content

             PdfPCell contentCell = new PdfPCell(content);
             contentCell.Border =1;
             contentCell.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_TOP;
             contentCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;

             contentTable.AddCell(contentCell);
            #endregion



            PdfPCell firstHeader = new PdfPCell(empty);
            firstHeader.Border = 0;
            firstHeader.FixedHeight = 17f;
            outerTable.AddCell(firstHeader);             

            PdfPCell secondHeader = new PdfPCell(patient);
            secondHeader.Border = 0;
            secondHeader.FixedHeight = 17f;
            secondHeader.VerticalAlignment = 2;
            outerTable.AddCell(secondHeader);

            PdfPCell thirdHeader = new PdfPCell(documentStatusP);
            thirdHeader.Border = 0;
            thirdHeader.FixedHeight = 17f;
            thirdHeader.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
            thirdHeader.VerticalAlignment = 2;
            outerTable.AddCell(thirdHeader);

            PdfPCell forthHeader = new PdfPCell(empty);
            forthHeader.Border = 0;
            forthHeader.FixedHeight = 17f;
            outerTable.AddCell(forthHeader);


            PdfPCell outerTblCell = new PdfPCell(outerTable);
            outerTblCell.Border = 0;

            PdfPCell contentTblCell = new PdfPCell(contentTable);
            contentTblCell.Border = 0;


            mainTable.AddCell(outerTblCell);
            mainTable.AddCell(contentTblCell);

            document.Add(mainTable);
            if (i != lst.Count - 1)
                document.NewPage();
        }

        document.Close();

    }
```

This displayed the report and all the required values except that in the content table when the document text has very long lines it runs out of the margins of the page and you cant see it. Is there a way to better achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I start by fixing the margins of the page like so:

```
const float leftMargin = 34;
const float rightMargin = 34;
const float topMargin = 134;
const float bottomMargin = 36;

var document = new Document(PageSize.A4, leftMargin, rightMargin, topMargin, bottomMargin);
```

I then fix the width of the table. In my case the document is on a portrait A4 page, so I know the max width of the page and can subtract the margins. I build the table like so:

```
private PdfPTable CreateTable()
{
    const float tableWidth = 527;

    var table = new PdfPTable(1)
    {
        HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT,
        TotalWidth = tableWidth,
        LockedWidth = true,
        SplitLate = true,
        SplitRows = true  
    };

    return table;
}
```

Comment: This is more of a refactoring suggestion. I did what you suggested but when i add the outer and content tables in my main table the two cells hold the space in parallel. is there a setting to make this two cells overlap so the first field could be on top and next  at the bottom?

Comment: I'm not exactly following, but do you mean the content inside you table cell sits side by side, as oppose to on top of each other?

Comment: mainTable.AddCell(outerTblCell);
 mainTable.AddCell(contentTblCell); these two tables are being displayed side by side in the mainTable

Comment: I think that is because you have specified 2 columns for the `mainTable`. Hence, when you call `AddCell` twice, it creates it into two cells on the same row. You need to set the `colspan` property on `outerTblCell` and `contentTblCell` to 2. This will cause it to take up the full width of the `mainTable`, and hence  sit on top of each other.

Comment: Yo have led me to the right direction so i will mark it as an answer. Thanks!